# Is there somewhere to go to get notes for package updates?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, apt-get

Most times when I start up my Ubuntu VM, I'll open the terminal and check for updates.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I'll then get a list of the packages to be upgraded:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  firefox firefox-locale-en libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-dev libegl1-mesa-drivers
  libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa
  libgles2-mesa libgles2-mesa-dev libopenvg1-mesa libwayland-egl1-mesa
  libxatracker2 linux-libc-dev linux-libc-dev:i386 mesa-common-dev tzdata
  tzdata-java
```

But I have no idea what all of these are for/what they all do (usually only a subset)/what is being changed about them.  I want to better understand what is happening.  Is there a place I can go to check the release notes for each package and/or just get notes on what those packages even do?

Comment: Out of scope, we don't deal with off site resources

Comment: @random - perfectly valid question imho... he/she simply needs to know about `apt-listchanges`. https://askubuntu.com/questions/4068/can-i-see-more-details-of-an-aptitude-dist-upgrade/4070#4070

Answer (score 1):

You can search for notes on packages here:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/